# Drupal 9. He usado el comando 'drush cr' y ha desaparecido my aplicacion. Me redirige al instalador como si fuera la primera vez que entro

Tags: php, drupal, drupal9

estoy siguiendo unos cursos de http://drupaladicto.es, en concreto iba por aqui:

https://www.drupaladicto.es/snippet/configuracion-desarrollo-local-drupal-8.

En el **punto 5** :

> Dentro de **settings.local.yml** descomentamos estas líneas:

> `# $settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';` 
> `# $settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';`

Como no lo encontraba he ido a al fichero `settings.php` que si existe y a demas contenia dichas lineas.

Hago todo eso, actualizo la pagina y me redirije a la creacion de la misma, ahora porque estoy aprendiendo, pero este fallo se cargaria el proyecto entero, ¿**alguna manera para remediar mi error de novato**?

Answer (score 0):

Para activar las opciones de desarrollo en Drupal tienes que hacer tres cosas:

Dirigirte al archivo settings.php y eliminar los comentarios de esta línea que suele encontrarse al final del archivo, justo antes de la configuración de la base de datos:

```html
/**
 * Load local development override configuration, if available.
 *
 * Create a settings.local.php file to override variables on secondary (staging,
 * development, etc.) installations of this site.
 *
 * Typical uses of settings.local.php include:
 * - Disabling caching.
 * - Disabling JavaScript/CSS compression.
 * - Rerouting outgoing emails.
 *
 * Keep this code block at the end of this file to take full effect.
 */
#
if (file_exists($app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php')) {
  include $app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php';
}
```

Una vez tengas esto listo, crear el archivo settings.local.php en la misma ruta con el siguiente contenido (he eliminado los comentarios para que no quede muy larga la respuesta):

```html
<?php

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile


assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE, TRUE);
\Drupal\Component\Assertion\Handle::register();

$settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/development.services.yml';
$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';
$config['system.performance']['css']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
$config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['discovery_migration'] = 'cache.backend.memory';
$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['extension_discovery_scan_tests'] = TRUE;
$settings['rebuild_access'] = TRUE;
$settings['skip_permissions_hardening'] = TRUE;
```

Por último te faltaría crear el archivo development.services.yml dentro de la carpeta "sites" con el siguiente contenido:

```html
# Local development services.
#

# To activate this feature, follow the instructions at the top of the
# 'example.settings.local.php' file, which sits next to this file.
parameters:
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
  twig.config:
    debug: true
    auto_reload: true
    cache: false
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
```

Ahora sólo queda borrar caché y listo.

> El archivo settings.php no deberías modificarlo en exceso salvo que
> estés completamente seguro de lo que estás haciendo.

Con estos cambios, cuando quieras pasar a producción tu sitio bastará con eliminar el archivo settings.local.php (o renombrarlo).

Para solucionar tu problema actual, descarga en otra carpeta Drupal y copia el contenido del settings.php en tu Drupal actual (pero asegúrate de no reemplazar los datos de conexión que estarán al final del mismo).